# How do i add iscreatable and isupdateable methods in the following apex class?

Tags: apex

```
global class Async{

    @future
    public static void sendEmail(Set<Id> sendList){
        List <Notes__c> notesList = new List<Notes__c>();
        notesList.clear();
        for(List<EmailMessage> emailmsglist:[select Id,parentId,Parent.Email__c,Parent.Contact.Email,ToAddress, FromAddress, Subject, TextBody, HTMLBody, CreatedDate from EmailMessage where id in :sendList] )
        {
            for(EmailMessage emlist :emailmsglist){

                Notes__c note= new Notes__c(); // Create a note object 
                if(Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.Case__c.isCreateable()){
                    note.Case__c= emlist.parentid;}
                    if(emlist.HTMLBody != NULL && emlist.HTMLBody != ''){
                        if(Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.Message__c.isCreateable()){
                             note.Message__c = emlist.HTMLBody;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        note.Message__c = emlist.TextBody;
                    }
                    if(Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.Sent_To__c.isCreateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.From__c.isCreateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.Subject__c.isCreateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.fields.Datetime_Created__c.isCreateable()){
                        note.Sent_To__c = emlist.ToAddress;
                        note.From__c = emlist.FromAddress;
                        note.Subject__c = emlist.Subject;
                        note.Datetime_Created__c = emlist.CreatedDate;
                    }
                    if (emlist.Parent.Contact.Email == emlist.ToAddress || emlist.Parent.Email__c == emlist.ToAddress) // If the email is the same as Case's contact email or Email__c on Case itself, the type is a response.
                    {
                        note.Type__c = 'Response';
                    }
                    else {
                        note.Type__c = 'Forward/Others';
                    }
                    notesList.add(note); // Add note object to the list
                }
            }

            if(notesList.size()>0) {
                if(Schema.sObjectType.Notes__c.isCreateable()) {
                    insert notesList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not to be snarky, but a good start would be to declare those two methods like you would any other method. Beyond that, I encourage you to read [ask], and then [edit] your question to include more details. What are you trying to accomplish by adding these methods? What are you trying to check to see if it is/is not updateable or createable? What have you tried so far? Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking how to properly enforce Field-Level Security. A good place to start is the Salesforce documentation [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS).

To sum up, you need to call `isUpdateable()` on the schema object for each field that you're attempting to update, and `isCreateable()` on the schema object for each field you're attempting to populate on creation. Example from the linked documentation:

```
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Status__c.isUpdateable()) {
    // don't update, or show an error
}
```

Likewise for creation:

```
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isCreateable()) {
```

You seem to already be doing this for your `Notes__c` object upon creation. Since you're not performing any updates or DML on other objects, it's not clear to me why you'd need to add more of this type of code. You *do* have some inconsistencies in your logic, and you're missing a check for `Type__c`, but you seem to be on the right path.